# Update state of like button in Backbone View

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, model

In the following code, I have a view which extends from another view (but does not inherit any functionality, only renders the template) and a model which I want to implement now. My view is for a like button, which I need to retrieve the state of the like button from the server each time the page is loaded. I am not sure how to do this using the model. Do I need to have an Ajax call in the model retrieving the state from the server or does that call fall into the view?

This is my code:

```
var likeButton = Backbone.Model.extend ({

    initialize: function () {
        this.isLiked = /* need something here! Ajax call to get state of button from server? */
    }
});

var LikeButtonView = BaseButtonView.extend({ // extends form a previews view which simply extends from backbone and render's the template

    template: _.template($('#like-button').html()),
    sPaper: null,
    sPolyFill: null,
    sPolyEmpty: null,
    isLiked: false,

    events: {
        "click .icon": "like",
    },

    model: new likeButton (),

    initialize: function (options) {
        BaseButtonView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]); // inherit from BaseButtonView
        this.likeButn = $("button.icon", this.$el);
        this.svgNode = this.likeButn.find("svg").get(0); // find the svg in the likeButn and get its first object
        this.sPaper = Snap(this.svgNode); // pass in the svg object into Snap.js
        this.sPolyFill = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-solid');
        this.sPolyEmpty = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-empty');

        if (this.model.isLiked) {
            this.likeButn.addClass("liked");
        } else if (!this.model.isLiked) {
            this.likeButn.addClass("unliked");
        }

    },

    like: function() {
        this._update();
    },

    _update: function () {
        if ( !this.isLiked ) { // if isLiked is false, remove class, add class and set isLiked to true, then animate svg to liked position
            this._like();
        } else if ( this.isLiked ) { // is isLiked is false, remove class, add class, set isLiked to false, then animate svg to unliked position
            this._unlike();
        }
    },

    _like: function() {
        this.likeButn.removeClass("unliked");
        this.likeButn.addClass("liked");
        this.isLiked = true;
        this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
        this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't-9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    },

    _unlike: function() {

        this.likeButn.removeClass("liked");
        this.likeButn.addClass("unliked");
        this.isLiked = false;
        this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't0,0'}, 300, mina.easeinout);
        this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to implement the 'like' button's knowledge of the current state of the page: A hidden field delivered from the HTML, an Ajax call to the server, or generating your javascript server-side with the state of the like model already active.

Let's start with the basics.  Your code is a bit of a mess.  A *model* contains the state of your application, and a *view* is nothing more than a way of showing that state, receiving a message when the state changes to update the show, and sending messages to the model to change the state.  The model and the view communicate via Backbone.Events, and the view and the DOM communicate via jQuery.Events.  You have to learn to keep those two separate in your mind.

Here, I've turned your "like" model into an actual model, so that the Backbone.Event hub can see the changes you make.

```
var likeButton = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults: {
        'liked': false
    }
});
```

Now in your view, the initial render will draw the state in gets from the model.  When a DOM event (described in the 'events' object) happens, your job is to translate that into a state change on the model, so my "toggleLike" only changes the *model*, not the view.  However, when the model changes (explicitly, when the "liked" field of the model changes), the view will then update itself automatically.

That's what makes Backbone so cool.  It's the way views *automatically* reflect the reality of your models.  You only have to get the model right, and the view works.  You coordinate the way the view reflects the model in your initialization code, where it's small and easy to reason about what events from the model you care about.

```
var LikeButtonView = BaseButtonView.extend({ 

    template: _.template($('#like-button').html()),

    events: {
        "click .icon": "toggleLike",
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        BaseButtonView.prototype.initialize.call(this, options); // inherit from BaseButtonView
        // A shortcut that does the same thing.
        this.likeButn = this.$("button.icon");
        this.model.on('change:liked', this._updateView, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        BaseButtonView.prototype.render.call(this);
        // Don't mess with the HTML until after it's rendered.
        this.likeButn.addClass(this.model.isLiked ? "liked", "unliked");
    },

    toggleLike: function() {
        this.model.set('liked', !this.model.get('liked'));
    },

    _updateView: function () {
        if (this.model.get('liked')) {
            this._showLikedState();
        } else {
            this._showUnlikedState();
        }
    }
});
```

How the like *model* gets initialized is, as I said above, up to you.  You can set a URL on the model's options and in your page's startup code tell it to "fetch", in which case it'll get the state from some REST endpoint on your server.  Or you can set it to a default of 'false'.  Or you can set it in hidden HTML (a hidden div or something) and then use your page startup code to find it:

```
new LikeButtonView({model: new LikeButton({}, {url: "/where/page/state/is"}));
```

or

```
new LikeButtonView({model: new LikeButton({liked: $('#hiddendiv').data('liked')}, {}));
```

If you're going to save the liked state, I'd recommend the URL.  Then you have someplace to save your data.